# nginx proxy_pass SSL :wrong version number

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxypass

**Error Code: 500:**

> 2023/07/30 09:55:29 [error] 4277#4277: *54 SSL_do_handshake() failed
> (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL
> handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: myserver.com,
> request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://192.168.0.36:8081/",
> host: "myserver.com"

- 192.168.0.1 - router

  192.168.0.36 - nextcloud server on 8081 port (HTTP work fine)

  192.168.0.37 - webserver nginx

**www->192.168.0.37 proxy_pass to -> 192.168.0.36 nextcloud**

nginx.ssl.conf:

```
server {
    listen      192.168.0.37:443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com ;
    error_log   /var/log/apache2/domains/myserver.com.error.log error;

    ssl_certificate     /home/user1/conf/web/myserver.com/ssl/myserver.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user1/conf/web/myserver.com/ssl/myserver.com.key;
    ssl_stapling        on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # TLS 1.3 0-RTT anti-replay
    if ($anti_replay = 307) { return 307 https://$host$request_uri; }
    if ($anti_replay = 425) { return 425; }

    include /home/user1/conf/web/myserver.com/nginx.hsts.conf*;

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known\/|file) {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.36:8081;

    location /error/ {
        alias /home/user1/web/myserver.com/document_errors/;
    }
    proxy_hide_header Upgrade;

    include /home/user1/conf/web/myserver.com/nginx.ssl.conf_*;
}
```

**I try add**

```
proxy_ssl_name myserver.com;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

no help

Comment: Is `192.168.0.36:8081` running an http server or an https server? Perhaps you need `proxy_pass http://192.168.0.36:8081;` instead.

Comment: In short: if nextcloud is working with plain HTTP on port 8081 (as you say) then it does not work also with HTTPS on the same port. The `proxy_pass` should therefore point to `http://...` (plain HTTP) and not to `https://...` (HTTPS).

Comment: thanks everyone. it worked
---
and how to make ssl taken from 192.168.0.36 NGP
www->192.168.0.37 proxy_pass to -> 192.168.0.36 nextcloud+nginx proxy manager with ssl